# How do I fix the jest unit testing - "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined" on importing states from my Authcontext provider?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write a unit test for my React components using Jest and enzyme.

My component contains some 'states' which are actually imported from an AuthContext Provider.

This my test code -

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
import Destination from "../Components/Destination"


Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Destination Component', () => {
   it('should add the selected Destination to the state', () => {
      const planet = []
      const selectDestinationInstance = shallow(<Destination/>)
      const selectDOM = selectDestinationInstance.find("#demo-simple-select")
      selectDOM.simulate('change', {'target' : {name : "Donlon"}})
      expect(planet[0]).toequal("Donlon")
   })
})
```

And this is the component - Destination I am testing -

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../Context/AuthProvider.js";
import "../css/Destination.css";
import Vehicles from "../Components/Vehicles";
import "../css/Vehicle.css"
import {
  Paper,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  FormControl,
  Select,
  Grid
} from "@mui/material";

function Destination() {
  const {
    selectedPlanets,
    SetselectedPlanets,
    AllPlanets,
  } = useContext(AuthContext);

   const OnSelectPlanet = (e, key) => {
    const clonedSelectedPlanets = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedPlanets));
    clonedSelectedPlanets[key] = e.target.value;
    SetselectedPlanets(clonedSelectedPlanets);
  };


  return (
    <>
      <div className="Parent_Card">
        <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center">
        {selectedPlanets.map((planet, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="PlanetsAndVehicles" key={index}>
              <Grid item xs = {2} md = {6} lg = {12}>
              <Paper elevation={5}>
                <FormControl fullWidth key = {index}>
                  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
                    Destination {index + 1}
                  </InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select"
                    key={index}
                    value={selectedPlanets[index]}
                    onChange={(e) => OnSelectPlanet(e, index)}
                  >
                    <MenuItem key={index} value={selectedPlanets[index]}>
                      {selectedPlanets[index]}
                    </MenuItem>
                    {OptionsToRender}
                  </Select>
                  <>
                    {selectedPlanets[index] ? (
                      <>
                        <div className="Distance_measure">
                          Distance - {getDistance(index)}
                        </div>
                        <Vehicles
                          index={index}
                          PlanetDistance={getDistance(index)}
                        />
                      </>
                    ) : (
                      <></>
                    )}
                  </>
                </FormControl>
              </Paper>
              </Grid>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Destination;
```

The error I am getting - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selectedPlanets').

I am expecting my test to pass.